# Implement coupon to BuyNow button without PHP

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm trying to implement the use of coupons to my "buy now" button but the only example I ran into is the one that use PHP combined with the button HTML code.

My hosted site does not support PHP so I am looking for an alternative.

I was following this tutorial:youtube.com/watch?v=4Y6EcOM_F10 
this

This is the example code I was trying to follow:

```
<?php

$hostedButtonId = "";
$amount = 0;

$arr = array(
"take5" => array("hostedButtonId" => "", "discount" => "5"),
"take10" => array("hostedButtonId" => "", "discount" => "10")
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == $_POST["couponCode"])
    {
        $hostedButtonId = $value["hostedButtonId"];
        $discount = $value["discount"];
        $amount = ($amount - $discount);
        break;
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Coupon Code</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="apDiv1">
<h3>Slick Tie $<?php echo  $amount; ?></h3>
<img src="tie.png" width="72" height="130">
</div>

<div id="apDiv2">
A tie by any other name would still look as sweet.  But a tie at a lower price ...
<br><br>
<form action="coupon-code.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="couponCode"  placeholder="coupon code" >
<input type="submit" name="submitCouponCode" value="apply coupon">
</form>
<br><br>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="<?php echo  $hostedButtonId; ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any suggestions?

I thought maybe I can use JS instead of PHP.

Would it work?

Thanks

Comment: It might be worthwhile posting a link to the PayPal pages that you've read describing the use of these coupons. For example if there is no interactive content in the coupon code it may just be that they're suggesting PHP but you can extract the required HTML. However if it requires some interaction with user data you're probably stuck.

Comment: I was following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y6EcOM_F10

Comment: As that's a 12 minute video tutorial I don't really have time to watch it; also as it's a 3rd party tutorial I think your best way of getting an answer is to message the person who recorded it.

Comment: I added the example code I tried to work with, thought maybe I could use JS instead of PHP

Comment: You could easily put that content there inside JavaScript. However you'd also have to put the coupon codes in your JS file, meaning that any user could just read the script on their system and type in the code. Now clearly that's not ideal, however I'd imagine the number of users who'd think to do that is minimal.